# ConvLSTM2D for one-to-many network

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, lstm, attributeerror

I want to use some ConvLSTM2D layer for a multi output regression model. One image should be the input and depending on the image a certain number of values should be the output padded by zeros. My Question is what function to use to have the same image as an input?

If I'm using

```
import keras.backend as K
K.tile(input, number_timesteps)
```

I'm getting the error:
AttributeError:'Tensor' object has no attribute '_keras_history'.
Is there any other way to solve this or do I have to input the same image multiple times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All keras tensors in a model must be produced by a `Layer`.
When you use backend functions, you're not using layers.

You can use `Lambda` layers to wrap custom and backend functions:

```
tiledOutputs = Lambda(lambda x: K.tile(x, number_timesteps))(imageInputs)
```

Or add the layer to a sequential model:

```
model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.tile(x, number_timesteps)))
```

But you're probably looking for `K.stack([x]*number_timesteps, axis=1)`.

Comment: The problem is that K.repeat is only for 2D Arrays including the Batchsize

Comment: @j.dings Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks! But when I'm using the Lambda layer I get the error message "can't pickle NotImplementedType objects"

Comment: ???? Is that in a `model.save()` or something? What is your Keras version?

Comment: I'm using keras.layers.merge.concatenate now and concatenate the input with itself and it works now. Thanks for your help

Comment: Cool idea :))).